# What is the difference between workflow and dataflow?

Tags: spring, workflow, microservices, dataflow, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm looking at Spring Cloud Date Flow, before that I watched Activiti and Camunda(this is workflow engine). And I can't understand what is the difference between these concepts as workflow and dataflow? and сan we call Spring Cloud Data Flow the workflow engine?

Sorry, I'm newer in this topic.

I will be glad to any answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activiti and I believe Camunda, too, is a BPM tool. Spring Cloud Data Flow (SCDF) is *not* one!

SCDF's core premise is to solve data integration challenges. Whether it is pure ingest, data processing, or persistence, you'd be able to build a coherent data pipeline made of these operations rapidly.

To get there, you can leverage any of the out-of-the-box [streaming/task applications](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/#available-applications), or you could build your custom application with the help of [Spring Cloud Stream](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/) and [Spring Cloud Task](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-task/) microservice frameworks. These applications can benefit from standalone development, testing in isolation, and native CI/CD practices. Once the application is ready, you can [register and use](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.2.0.RC1/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-register-apps) them directly in SCDF.

As well, SCDF comes with a [runtime abstraction](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.2.0.RC1/reference/htmlsingle/#arch-intro) and with that, you have the option to orchestrate data pipelines made of microservice applications on a variety of cloud-native runtime platforms - one could avoid vendor specific lock-ins.

Comment: Thanks for your answer) I have a few questions: 1) I don't understand the purpose of the SCDF, because the custom application with Spring Cloud Stream and Spring Cloud Task can work without the SCDF?
2) In the documentation I saw that the SCDF can run on different runtime platforms (for example, Kubernetes), what advantages does the Kubernetes give for the SCDF, why can't I work without it?

Comment: Refer to this thread for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39781239/what-are-the-benefits-of-spring-cloud-dataflow